# Media query and text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to find a way to place my headline and sub-headline, so they are aligned with eachother. But when i make it fit on 1 device, the text is jumping around on another device. That means I am just going around in circles.

Is there a way where I can say on all mobile devices the margin should be fx: 20px from the left, or how are you guys doing it?

**HTML**

```
<div class="max-container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    @CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("Grid")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header-text h1 {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 160px;
}




.header-text h2 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #fff;

}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .header-text h2 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;

}
```

Comment: Paste your whole code. Likely it is a width issue. Try setting the width on your breakpoints. Also make sure to include viewport meta tag.

Comment: As it is, you only have your left margin set for the h2 on media devices. Be sure to declare your margins above as well. Who knows what other elements are affecting the h1—could be issues with width, margin, padding, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The relevant CSS I have is only this. The content and grid is from Umbraco, so there is no more html code.

Comment: Would you set the width in px or %?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        .header-text h2, .header-text h1 {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
    }
```

You don't need to repeat all the other values if they stay the same — you'll also notice you can combine selectors together, which makes your code lighter.

Also, be careful about using **!important** (it can make future coding really messy). Try to add specificity before you use that.